# Gaining advantages without spending XP

Tags: gurps-4e

Is there a method that allows you to take advantages without actually spending experience? For example getting unkillable 1 by becoming a vampire or do you have to spend experience regardless of the way you acquire an advantage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, mainly by doing something in the game world that has that effect on your character.** Get yourself enlisted in an army or police force and you will tend to get Rank and/or Law Enforcement Powers, for example.

Getting turned by a vampire would make you a vampire, which would include whatever advantages and disadvantages define a vampire in the GM's campaign, likely including that Unkillable 1 you wanted. Of course, your character might sooner or later also become an NPC in the process (or not, depending on the GM).

**It is up to the GM to choose how much to care about character points and how to handle such situations.** There are some suggestions in the Basic Set. In general, the in-game events determine what happens, and could lead to you gaining advantages, and the GM decides whether that has some meaningful effect in terms of character points or not, for examples:

- Some GMs may not pay much attention to character points, particularly after play has started. Your PC just gains or loses abilities, status, wealth, possessions, allies, enemies etc depending on what happens, without caring what your point total is. (As a GURPS GM since the game came out in 1987, I tend to only use character points as a rough guideline and measure of balance/impact, and would tend to just play out what happens logically and not pay much/any attention to character points.)
- Some GMs may follow the suggestion that PCs do need to pay for acquired advantages, but this doesn't keep them from acquiring them - just from investing earned points on other things until the new advantages are paid for. What the exact payment plan for this may vary from GM to GM (e.g. maybe for every earned point spent on something else, a point needs to be spent buying off an already-acquired-in-play advantage).
- Some GMs may cause "un-paid-for" abilities to erode or cause other side-effects to try to balance point totals.

For example, if your character gets a lot of wealth in the game but doesn't invest earned points in the Wealth advantage, they may rule that your PC can't handle it and tends to have dysfunctional behavior to compensate (e.g. spending sprees, acquiring other temporary mental disadvantages that make sense to balance the points, etc).

For another example, if a PC gained a Patron or Ally, they may logically also gain an Enemy or Reputation that logically goes along with that.

- Some GMs may react to acquired advantages by in-game effects that aren't tracked with points or handled with advantage rules. They may or may not be thinking of points when they assess the results of acquiring advantages, but there are liable to be logical situational effects of gaining an advantage, with various people reacting to you quite differently.

Your example of becoming a vampire and gaining Unkillable 1 is a great example of a situation where the character's life... (er, *un*life) and situation are liable to be changed forever (and/or ended quickly despite Unkillable 1) by what happens as a result, without character points coming into it at all, and no real need/reason/value in doing point accounting about it.

*A natural approach that takes character points into account but isn't terribly forced or unnatural is to ignore character points at first, and play out the logical consequences of a change in character abilities, and then just assign points to whatever the consequences were after the situation stabilizes a bit, and only require some sort of point impact if the net result is positive.* And, if the player played the transformation events well, they could also have earned more points in the process.

- Some GMs may have different approaches depending on the type of advantage you gained, making characters buy off or compensate with disadvantages for some types of advantages gained in play, but not for other types.

Answer (score 2):

This is, as always, up to the GM. GURPS doesn't have one hard rule for this, because it's a toolkit, rather than a game, complete with setting and society, in a can.

In most games, the PCs are on comparable, if not identical, point totals, and giving one of them the extra 150 points of the Vampire template from p.262 of the Basic Set without it being paid for could be perceived as unfair by the other players. There are several ways to handle this:

- Some groups simply aren't worried about PCs having similar point totals, although the other PCs might well be worried about having their comrade turned into a blood-sucking undead monster.
- If a PC becoming a vampire is treated as a problem, it's possible to get them turned back, and the other PCs are going to treat that as a priority, then there's no need to worry about the points, because they're a plot device and the vampire won't be keeping them.
- If it isn't possible to get a vampire restored to life, but the new vampire is going to die soon, either because the other PCs will (regretfully) do it, or someone else is likely to do the job, then this is also a plot device, rather than a lasting change in the character, and there's no need to worry about the points.
- If it's a game where becoming a vampire is acceptable to the PC, and their comrades, then yes, you need to pay for the kewl powrz. But no PC has 150 spare points lying around. GURPS makes it practical to pay in instalments, by giving a new vampire reduced versions of the advantages of a mature vampire, and/or additional disadvantages. The disadvantages can be bought off and the full powers bought, in small slices as the character gains experience.
- If the *whole party* are going to become vampires, over a reasonably short period of game time, then again, this is a plot device, and the PCs end up with similar point totals.

If you would like suggestions on making a vampire template less powerful and susceptible to being bought in instalments, that's a different question, so please ask it separately, and specify which vampire template you're interested in.